# How to grant access to webpage whitout logging in?

Tags: php

It's possible to get a users ip adress with php like:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']
```

Is it safe to have a website that allows only a certain ip adress
and no login with password etc?

What more options is out there for only letting some users onto a webpage?
 Beside from a login page.

I'm thinking like:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 123.123.1.1){
   echo "Welcome!";
else{
   echo "You do not have permission to enter this site";
}
```

**EDIT**

I would use a "kiosk" browser if i found one that can store passwords.
The allowed user should be a computer, not a human user.

Let´s say that you can enter a website from your job, but not from home.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on IP address. Maybe create a hash and append it to the link as a query string.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Can you give me an example of this?

Comment: Just added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly recommend you to use a standard authorisation flow, the following might assist you: (The risk is on you...)

> page.php?pass=oursecretpass

```
<?php
$pass = hash('ripemd160', $_GET['pass']);

if($pass == hash('ripemd160', 'oursecretpass')){
  echo "Welcome";
} else {
  echo "Error.";
}
```

**A slightly better option** would be to first check the output of hash('ripemd160', 'any string you would like to try');
and use it as the "?pass" value. So let's say the output of this hash function is: ec457d0a974c48d5685a7efa03d137dc8bbde7e3

You send the following link to your friend:

> page.php?pass=ec457d0a974c48d5685a7efa03d137dc8bbde7e3

And in the php code just change the first line to:

```
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
```

Comment: So basicly what this does is that it combines "oursecretpass" with a hashed "ripemd160" that is hidden in php.. But "ripemd160" would be a ip adress? I do not want the viewer on the page to know how he/she got access..

Comment: I guess if i hash the ip of the user.. and hash the ip of the allowed ip.. and then check if they match.. then i can use a link.. that you cannot copy and take home with you..?

Comment: The problem with IP is that it can be modified. While having a key/hash is constant. But it still would be accessed from any computer.

Comment: How easy is it to modify and ip? How big is the risk i mean?